# Python - raw text to list of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following string that need to be converted to a list of dicts.

`'"Date","Volume/Length","Length/Width","Weight gm":"08-Dec-2018","       23.19","        2.13","        1.32":"08-Jan-2019","       22.70","        5.22","        1.02":'`

What would be the pythonic way to do this ? The keys would be  `"Date","Volume/Length","Length/Width","Weight gm"`

Comment: Looks like you could split on colons to get each row, then split on commas within a row to get each field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, convert the string to a nested `list`, where each inner `list` represents a row:

```
import re

string = '"Date","Volume/Length","Length/Width","Weight gm":"08-Dec-2018","       23.19","        2.13","        1.32":"08-Jan-2019","       22.70","        5.22","        1.02":'

nested_list = [[value.strip() for value in row.replace('"', '').split(',')] for row in string.strip(':').split(':')]

# Colons divide rows, so there shouldn't be any at the ends
```

Then transpose the nested `list` so that each inner `list` now represents a *column*. In each column the first element is the column name and the rest are values in that column. Per this schema, we can perform slicing to get key-value pairs for the final `dict`:

```
transposed_list = list(zip(*nested_list))
result = {column[0]: column[1:] for column in transposed_list}

# This part can be changed to list(column[1:]) if you want the inner elements to be lists

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'Date': ('08-Dec-2018', '08-Jan-2019'), 
 'Volume/Length': ('23.19', '22.70'), 
 'Length/Width': ('2.13', '5.22'), 
 'Weight gm': ('1.32', '1.02')}
```

Comment: `>>> s = '"Date","Volume/Length","Length/Width","Weight gm":"08-Dec-2018","       23.19","        2.13","        1.32":"08-Jan-2019","       22.70","        5.22","        1.02":'
>>> s.strip(':').split(':')
['"Date","Volume/Length","Length/Width","Weight gm"', '"08-Dec-2018","       23.19","        2.13","        1.32"', '"08-Jan-2019","       22.70","        5.22","        1.02"']`
with `split(':')` - I was expecting a list of lists rather than a list of strings - do you see the same ?

Comment: No, you need to `split` twice to get a `list` of `lists`.

Answer (score 1):

First extract out the keys as a list, and the values as a list of lists as  below

```
s = '"Date","Volume/Length","Length/Width","Weight gm":"08-Dec-2018","       23.19","        2.13","        1.32":"08-Jan-2019","       22.70","        5.22","        1.02":'

rows = s.split(':')
keys = rows[0].replace('"','').split(',')
# List of all keys
print(keys)
#['Date', 'Volume/Length', 'Length/Width', 'Weight gm']

values = []
for i in range(1,len(rows)-1):
    elems = rows[i].split(',')
    value = []
    for elem in elems:
        parsed_elem = elem.replace('"','').strip()
        value.append(parsed_elem)
    values.append(value)
#List of all values, as a list of lists
print(values)
#[['08-Dec-2018', '23.19', '2.13', '1.32'], ['08-Jan-2019', '22.70', '5.22', '1.02']]
```

After this you can use keys and values to convert it into a list of dicts

```
dict_list = []
for value in values:
    dct = {}
    for idx, key in enumerate(keys):
        dct[key] = value[idx]
    dict_list.append(dct)
print(dict_list)
#{'Date': '08-Dec-2018', 'Volume/Length': '23.19', 
#'Length/Width': '2.13', 'Weight gm': '1.32'}, 
#{'Date': '08-Jan-2019', 'Volume/Length': '22.70', 
#'Length/Width': '5.22', 'Weight gm': '1.02'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
input_str = '"Date","Volume/Length","Length/Width","Weight gm":"08-Dec-2018","       23.19","        2.13","        1.32":"08-Jan-2019","       22.70","        5.22","        1.02":'

input_str_formatted = input_str.replace('"', '')
input_list = input_str_formatted.split(':')

key_list = input_list[0].split(',')
val_list_1 = map( lambda x: x.strip() , input_list[1].split(',') )
val_list_2 = map( lambda x: x.strip() , input_list[2].split(',') )

result_dict = { key_list[i] : ( val_list_1[i], val_list_2[i] ) for i in range(len(key_list)) }
```

Hope it helps.